# How to get image src attribute as url instead of base64 string

Tags: jquery, html

I want to make a crawler using from apifier.com that could fetch image src url from this  [website](http://www.developer-tech.com/categories/Android/)

which have this img structure in the HTML:

```html
<img src="/media/img/news/xcrushed-oreo-cookie-topping-picture-id666954812.jpg.250x160_q96_crop.png.pagespeed.ic.6AnfnS_Jbx.webp">
```

when I fetch the src using this jquery code:

```
 $("article").find("img").attr("src")
```

it somehow returns:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACMAAAAZCAMAAACM5megAAAAM1BMVEUAAAD
```

which is not what I want. I wonder how to get the URI instead of base64 string (so I could add the website url to the string).

Comment: The website may be lazy-loading the images and what you see is a placeholder while the real images load. In most cases the src for the image is added as a custom html attribute which then gets swapped with the src attribute after the image is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is your url who returns Base64 image directly.
So, to get the url, you could add a data attribute like this :

```
<img data-url="/media/img/news/xcrushed-oreo-cookie-topping-picture-id666954812.jpg.250x160_q96_crop.png.pagespeed.ic.6AnfnS_Jbx.webp" src="/media/img/news/xcrushed-oreo-cookie-topping-picture-id666954812.jpg.250x160_q96_crop.png.pagespeed.ic.6AnfnS_Jbx.webp">
```

And get the value with :

```
$("article").find("img").data("url")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the solution given by @Ihazkode worked for me, therefore I will share it as an answer. As he says in the comment, the actual src url is replaced with the custom html attribute and replaced once the image has been loaded. E.g
First we need to find what is the custom html attribute where actual src url is stored.

like e.g:

```
<img data-src="/example.com/abc/xyz.jpg" ...>
```

Here, we can do something like:

```
image = page.get_attribute('data-src')
if not image:
    image = page.get_attribute('src')
```

as I said, it worked for me.